# for loop is iterating over the same value

Tags: javascript

So basically I have a set of questions(`<div>`s), all with the same class name and I want to simply loop through all of those classes and append the questions(`<div>`s) inside a container but at the minute it seems to just loop through it but only display the 1st question over and over or however many questions I put in.

```
if($('.option').hasClass('c_questions')){

  var y = document.getElementsByClassName('c_questions');
  for(var i = 0; i < y.length; i++){
    $('.main-body').append($('.c_questions').html());
  }
}
```

Comment: `y[i].innerHTML` should be used in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```js
  $('.c_questions').each(function(a){
    $('.main-body').append($(this).html()+" ");
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="c_questions">hi</div>
<div class="c_questions">hey</div>
 <div class="c_questions">test</div>

<p class="main-body"></p>
```

by edit into code. (squint suggested.)

```
if($('.option').hasClass('c_questions')){

var y = document.getElementsByClassName('c_questions');
for(var i = 0; i < y.length; i++){
$('.main-body').append(y[i].innerHTML);  
}                       ^^^^^change
 }
```

Comment: hm ... `"message": "'$' is undefined",`

Comment: it's not the missing html, it's more the snippet environment, which does not make sense.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use a `for` loop, look at jQuery's [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/).

So this would loop through each element with the class example below:

```js
$( ".test" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log($( this ).text() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">hi</div>
<div class="test">hey</div>
<div class="test">test</div>
```